# NAP clients are evaluated as non NAP-capable

Tags: nps, healthcheck

The setup: Active Directory domain, Remote Desktop Gateway server, NPS/NAP server (all Windows Server 2008 R2) and a few Windows 7 clients.

The RDG and NPS are set up and running with all Connection Request & Network policies and everything is well, except for NAP health checks. Whatever I do on client it is evaluated as non NAP-capable.

I start NAP Agent (napagent) service, enable Remote Desktop Gateway quarantine client in NAP Client config MMC (napclcfg.msc) and add my RDG URL https://rdg.company.com to Trusted Gateways list to no avail, the client Windows 7 machine ends up as "non NAP-capable".

netsh nap client show state command's output is fine too, everything looks ok as it should be according to NAP Quick Fixes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348494(v=ws.10).aspx

In event viewer of client machine I see NAP events from which I can guess that everything's ok from client's perspective too, client 79621 is successfully initialized and SystemHealthAgent seems to scan and (supposedly) succesfully build a SoH.

Still, obviously NAP server does not get a SoH from a client and thus classifies it as non NAP-capable for some weird reason.

Since I haven't found any further means to investigate and troubleshoot it, I would be grateful for any ideas and/or suggestions.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Some diag info below:

NAP client state:

```
PS C:\> netsh nap client show state

Client state:
----------------------------------------------------
Name                   = Network Access Protection Client
Description            = Microsoft Network Access Protection Client
Protocol version       = 1.0
Status                 = Enabled
Restriction state      = Not restricted
Troubleshooting URL    =
Restriction start time =
Extended state         =
GroupPolicy            = Not Configured

Enforcement client state:
----------------------------------------------------
Id                     = 79617
Name                   = DHCP Quarantine Enforcement Client
Description            = Provides DHCP based enforcement for NAP
Version                = 1.0
Vendor name            = Microsoft Corporation
Registration date      =
Initialized            = No

Id                     = 79619
Name                   = IPsec Relying Party
Description            = Provides IPsec based enforcement for Network Access Protection
Version                = 1.0
Vendor name            = Microsoft Corporation
Registration date      =
Initialized            = No

Id                     = 79621
Name                   = RD Gateway Quarantine Enforcement Client
Description            = Provides RD Gateway enforcement for NAP
Version                = 1.0
Vendor name            = Microsoft Corporation
Registration date      =
Initialized            = Yes

Id                     = 79623
Name                   = EAP Quarantine Enforcement Client
Description            = Provides Network Access Protection enforcement for EAP authenticated network connections, such
as those used with 802.1X and VPN technologies.
Version                = 1.0
Vendor name            = Microsoft Corporation
Registration date      =
Initialized            = No

System health agent (SHA) state:
----------------------------------------------------
Id                     = 79744
Name                   = Windows Security Health Agent

Description            = The Windows Security Health Agent monitors security settings on your computer.

Version                = 1.0

Vendor name            = Microsoft Corporation

Registration date      =
Initialized            = Yes
Failure category       = None
Remediation state      = Success
Remediation percentage = 0
Fixup Message          = (3237937214) - The Windows Security Health Agent has finished updating the security state of th
is computer.

Compliance results     =
Remediation results    =

Ok.
```

Network Access Protection\Operational event log on client:

```
Id      : 1027
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent notified the Windows Network Access Protection Service of a change in the security health state of the computer.

Id      : 1007
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent completed an offline scan.

Id      : 9
Message : The enforcement client 79621 successfully initialized.

Id      : 1002
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent was initialized successfully.
      Scan Interval: 1320 minutes.
      Time delay before first scan: 45 seconds.
      Time interval between manual remediation state change: 15 seconds.
      Manual remediation timeout interval: 150 seconds.

Id      : 4
Message : The System Health Agent 79744 successfully initialized.

Id      : 100
Message : Sending Health Information to WHC: NapAgent is Active(1)

Id      : 1001
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent detected a change in the status of Automatic Updates.

Id      : 1000
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent detected a change in the status of Antispyware.

Id      : 1000
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent detected a change in the status of Antivirus.

Id      : 1000
Message : The Windows Security Health Agent detected a change in the status of Firewall.

Id      : 9
Message : The enforcement client 79871 successfully initialized.

Id      : 26
Message : The NAP service has started.
      NAP has the following information for this computer:
       Computer name is HOSTNAME.CORP.COMPANY.COM.
      Domain status is: Domain Joined.
      The build number is: 7601.
      The OS SKU is: CLIENT.
      The service pack version is: 1.0.
      The processor type is: x64 (AMD or Intel).
```